# LibreOffice 7.1 Writer flickers and crashes

Tags: libreoffice, mate, ubuntu-mate

I am using Libreoffice 7.1.4.2 under Ubuntu-MATE 21.04.
According to the LO's about dialog: `User Interface: UI render: default; VCL: gtk3`

I only use the text processing „Writer“, nothing else.

[image]

#### Problem 1: my styles panel (on the right) on the right flickers all the time

...blinks, maybe 50-100ms to white and back... (but certainly not in a blink tag fashion, more of a “nervous redraw”)

- basically irregulary about once per second (1 Hz)
- more often with every keypresses happening
- not at all, if focus is on another application's windows
- only in the styles panel

So apparently triggered by some refresh mechanism.

#### Problem 2

I assume it's related, thus in one post. LibreOffice freezes my entire machine:

- mouse still movable, all screens showing (3 in total, including 2× 4K)
- that's all – no clicks, no hovers, no interaction
- no keyboard commands (i.e. for Run or Terminal or alt-Tab) working
- not even ctrl-alt F3, F6, F7 (for non-graphical login)
- only hard reset + reboot helps

#### Any ideas?

What log file to look into? How to put LibreOffice into a different rendering mode?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [LibreOffice 7.2.5.2 & Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS - flickering menus and right panel](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1388589/libreoffice-7-2-5-2-ubuntu-20-04-1-lts-flickering-menus-and-right-panel)

Comment: I am so sorry, pbhj and @onesimos, due to this and several other problems I decided to reinstall my machine from scratch, so I can't reproduce, neither good nor bad. — but thank you for your help!

Answer (score 2):

For the flickering, I had the exact same symptoms and found a solution in [this thread](https://askubuntu.com/a/1434282/608804).

The problem is probably an old, deprecated `.xinputrc` file in your home directory. Just delete it, reboot and the problem is solved. At least it worked for me.

Comment: Due to this and several other problems I decided to reinstall my machine from scratch, so I can't reproduce, neither good nor bad. — but truly thank you for your help!