# LibreOffice 7.2.5.2 & Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS - flickering menus and right panel

Tags: nvidia, libreoffice

Ubuntu 20.04.1 with latest updates. Display runs on Nvidia. Details:

```
Kernel: 5.11.0-46-generic x86_64 bits: 64 
Machine:   Type: Laptop System: LENOVO product: 4282A37 v: ThinkPad W520 serial: <filter> 
           Mobo: LENOVO model: 4282A37 serial: <filter> UEFI [Legacy]: LENOVO v: 8BET52WW (1.32 ) date: 09/27/2011 
CPU:       Topology: Quad Core model: Intel Core i7-2760QM bits: 64 type: MT MCP L2 cache: 6144 KiB 
           Speed: 908 MHz min/max: 800/3500 MHz Core speeds (MHz): 1: 908 2: 888 3: 1061 4: 897 5: 897 6: 886 7: 865 
           8: 924 
Graphics:  Device-1: Intel 2nd Generation Core Processor Family Integrated Graphics driver: i915 v: kernel 
           Device-2: NVIDIA GF108GLM [Quadro 1000M] driver: nvidia v: 390.144 
           Display: x11 server: X.Org 1.20.13 driver: modesetting,nvidia unloaded: fbdev,nouveau,vesa 
           resolution: 1920x1080~60Hz 
           OpenGL: renderer: Quadro 1000M/PCIe/SSE2 v: 4.6.0 NVIDIA 390.144
```

Since quiet some time the right panel (permanent issue) and the font selection et al. (on hover) are flickering. I tried some of the older suggestions here in the forum to no avail f. e. switching OpenCL on and off does not make a difference.

Any hint appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had this problem for years, regardless of LO and Linux desktop versions (currently I'm running Libreoffice 7.4 on Xubuntu 20.04). Very very irritating. Much of the toolbar would flicker on a fairly regular basis. None of the solutions out there worked for me. But, I finally solved it just now, thanks to this post:

https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=517671#c50

Turns out I had:

`GTK_IM_MODULE=xim`

set as an environment variable (use `printenv` to print out all your env variables). Looks like this was because I had an old file `.xinputrc` in my home directory, whose contents were `run_im xim`, which I think was manually setting the system input method to the old `xim` instead of the now default `ibus`. This file may have been inherited from an installation going all the way back to Ubuntu 10.10.

Deleting the file and rebooting solved it for me. No more flickering in Libreoffice! Amazing! Hope this helps.

Comment: Txs! Hmmm my `.xinputrc` tells me it's from 2018. Will try and report back here. -mgw

Comment: Looks like it's gone after restart. Also confirm that `.xinputrc` remains absent. Perfect! Txs a ton -mgw